# How to install Ultraviolet gem with Ruby 1.9.2 on Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, ruby1.9

I am trying to install the Ultraviolet gem on my Mac but am getting errors. It tries to install oniguruma as a dependency which (to my understanding) is not needed since Ruby 1.9 includes the necessary regex libraries.

How to install Ultraviolet gem with Ruby 1.9.2 on Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard

Comment: Also see [related question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103355/problem-installing-oniguruma-gem-on-snow-leopard).